# I'm trying to install the 'paddleocr' package and I've been encountering this error for a week

Tags: python, paddleocr

```
Building wheels for collected packages: PyMuPDF
  Building wheel for PyMuPDF (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for PyMuPDF (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [164 lines of output]
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py: sys.argv: ['setup.py', 'bdist_wheel', '--dist-dir', 'C:\\Users\\Foodo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-b4ci5zdq\\.tmp-5ct32kqh']
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py: os.getcwd(): C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_srk6g5\pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py: __file__: C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_srk6g5\pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py: $PYTHON_ARCH: None
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py: os.environ (57):
      pymupdf_64a6ee3eede34c87b0382963f0407892\setup.py:     ACSVCPORT: 17532
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
      Commutateurs propres au produit :

      /debugexe   Ouvre l'ex‚cutable sp‚cifi‚ … d‚boguer. La suite de
                  la ligne de commande est pass‚e … cet ex‚cutable sous la forme d'arguments.
      /diff               Compare deux fichiers. Accepte quatre paramŠtresÿ:
                  SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceDisplayName (facultatif),
                  TargetDisplayName (facultatif)
      /sqldbaction    D‚marrer SQL Server Data Tools et effectuer l'action sp‚cifi‚e dans la chaŒne d'arguments.
      /TfsLink    Ouvre Team Explorer et lance une visionneuse pour l'URI
                  d'artefact fourni si un URI de ce type est inscrit.

      Pour attacher le d‚bogueur … partir de la ligne de commande, utilisez :
          VsJITDebugger.exe -p <pid>
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\FOODOMARKET\lmd\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\FOODOMARKET\lmd\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\FOODOMARKET\lmd\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qdlfm_ws\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qdlfm_ws\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qdlfm_ws\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Foodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qdlfm_ws\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 641, in <module>
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd mupdf-1.21.1-source/&&"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" platform/win32/mupdf.sln /Build "ReleaseTesseract|x64" /Project mupdf' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMuPDF
Failed to build PyMuPDF
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMuPDF, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've been searching everywhere but still encountering the same error or other errors. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```bash
pip install "paddleocr>=2.0.1" --upgrade PyMuPDF==1.21.1
```